# yarn asb parsing error in compiling Assemblyscript smart contract

Tags: typescript, parsing, yarnpkg, nearprotocol, assemblyscript

Anyone encountered this error when running yarn asb? I'm trying to compile an assemblyscript smart contract.

gitpod /workspace/MyAssemblyContract (main) $ yarn asb
yarn run v1.22.17
$ /workspace/MyAssemblyContract/node_modules/.bin/asb
ERROR TS1110: Type expected.

export function createGame() {
^
in assembly/index.ts(19,29)

/workspace/MyAssemblyContract/node_modules/asbuild/node_modules/yargs/build/lib/yargs.js:1132
throw err;
^

[1 parse error(s)]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
gitpod /workspace/MyAssemblyContract (main) $

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have not added a return type

please take an hour to read through 10-20 example contracts here https://github.com/learn-near so you can get an idea of basic syntax of AssemblyScript